# How to check if a datetime variable occurs in the past twelve months

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

What I am trying to do is to see if a datetime variable has the value of a date at anytime in the past twelve months.

I tried using the DATEDIFF function but then I quickly discovered that this has rounding problems (a comparison between 31st DEC/1st JAN would count as 1 month for example, despite the fact only a day has passed between them)

To make this more accurate I could use -365 days as a parameter rather than -12 months however this still gives the problem of not taking into account leap years (not a common scenario but still one I'd ideally avoid!)

Any ideas as to how I can best go about this?

Comment: What date format are you using? Are hours and minutes included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with leap years can be solved with the DATEADD (datepart , number , date ) function.  You can specify minus one year from the current date.

```
where myDate between DATEADD (year , -1 , GETDATE() ) and GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186819.aspx) instead to subtract a year from today and compare that

```
@datetimevariable >= DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
```

Note: you don't need to compare the upper bound (GETDATE()) unless you have dates in the future.

Also, do you want exactly one year down to the hour and minute? If not, use this which is safe for [datatype precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) if `@datetimevariable` is `datetime` or `datetime2`, and you need this is a WHERE clause or such

`@datetimevariable >= CAST(DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()) as date)`

This works for leap years

```
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, -1, '20120301'), DATEADD(YEAR, -1, '20120229')

2011-03-01 00:00:00.000
2011-02-28 00:00:00.000
```

DATEDIFF works on specific boundary: start of month, start of year, midnight etc which is why it fails in this case

Answer (score 0):

DATEDIFF counts the number of partitions between the two dates, sorry to say there is no rounding issue, it does exactly what it says on the tin. YOUR best solution is probably to used DATEADD

```
WHERE MyVal BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())
```